# JDOM is not loading full document

Tags: java, maven, jdom

I've tried to load following XML file, which is located on an external server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
  <groupId>de.wolfi</groupId>
  <artifactId>pluginupdater</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20171127.140226</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>81</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20171127140226</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.0-20171127.140226-81</value>
        <updated>20171127140226</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>pom</extension>
        <value>1.0-20171127.140226-81</value>
        <updated>20171127140226</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.0-20171126.202453-56</value>
        <updated>20171126202453</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
    </snapshotVersions>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

But when I load the file and Display the Content the snapsnotVerions part is missing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>de.wolfi</groupId>
  <artifactId>pluginupdater</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20171127.140207</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>80</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20171127140207</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

I'm kinda stuck now and have no idea what's going on.

Here is my code I'm using to load the file:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("XXXX", "XXXX".toCharArray());
        }
    });

    try {
        SAXBuilder b = new SAXBuilder();
        b.setXMLFilter(null);
        Document doc = b.build(new URL(
                "http://XXXX/pluginupdater/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml"));
    /*  Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
        List<?> list = rootNode.getChildren();

        XMLOutputter outp = new XMLOutputter();


            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                Element node = (Element)list.get(i);


                outp.output(node.getContent(), System.out);

            }
*/
        outp.output(doc, System.out);
```

This should work exept if I forgot to remove some kind of standard filter... But it doesn't...

Comment: please post the essential part of your code, or create a [mcve]

Comment: @JimHawkins here you go

Comment: @WOLFI3654 - when you browse to the actual URL you have in the code `http://XXXX/pluginupdater/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml` are you sure you get the full XML out?

Comment: I agree to @rolfl . I've used your code, but I read the XML from file system with `Document doc = b.build(new File("test.xml"));` . `outp.output(doc, System.out);`gives the complete XML. Do you use `org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder` ?

Comment: Yeah. Unfortuanaly Sonatype Nexus is not sending the full XML to Clients with "Java" in theier user Agent.